# Screen Options drop-down does not show

Tags: plugins, wp-admin

The screen options drop-down menu on the *Appearance* → *Widgets* admin page doesn't do anything when I click it. This happened since I enabled accessibility mode from that drop-down menu.

How can I get the menu to re-appear, so I can disable accessibility mode?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it was the Social Media Widget plugin that caused my issue.

---

In general, to troubleshoot such an issue with the admin page:

1. Disable all plugins.
2. Check that the problem has been solved, i.e., it is a plugin that causes this.
3. Enable one plugin at a time and test, to find the culprit.
4. Disable that plugin.

Otherwise, it might be your theme. Like plugins, themes can cause issues on the admin page.

1. Switch to one of the default themes.
2. Check that the problem has been solved.
3. Now you know your theme is the culprit.
4. Don't use that theme.

Comment: I did it and don't solve... :(